# Python Regular Expression OR not matching

Tags: python, regex

For some reason,

```
m = re.search('(<[^pib(strong)(br)].*?>|</[^pib(strong)]>)', '</b>')
```

matches the string, but

```
m = re.search('(</[^pib(strong)]>)', '</b>')
```

does not. I am trying to match all tags that are *not*

```
<p>, <b>, </p>, </b>
```

and so on. Am I misunderstanding something about how '|' works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing it wrong. First of all, characters between `[]` are matched differently: `[ab]` will match either `a` or `b`, so in your case `[^pib(strong)]` will match everything that is not a `p`, an `i`, a `b`, a `(`, etc. (note the negation from `^`). Your first regex matching is merely a coincidence.

Also, you shouldn't be parsing html/xml with regex. Instead, use a proper xml parsing library, like lxml or beautifulsoup.

Here's a simple example with `lxml`:

```
from lxml import html
dom = html.fromstring(your_code)
illegal = set(dom.cssselect('*')) - set(dom.cssselect('p,b'))
for tag in illegal:
    do_something_with(tag)
```

(this is a small, probably sub-optimal example; it serves just to show you how easy it is to use such a library. Also, note that the library will wrap the code in a `<p>`, so you should take that into consideration)